# Windows 10 laptop changes brightness depending on the screen contents

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9350) running Windows 10 and I can't seem to disable the automatic brightness changing depending on what's on the screen. If the screen is primarily light the brightness will go up, and when it's primarily dark it'll dim. I'm having the same issue as outlined in these posts:

- [Laptop monitor brightness changes depending on image displayed](https://superuser.com/questions/540335/laptop-monitor-brightness-changes-depending-on-image-displayed)
- [Screen Brightness Changes Depending on Screen Contents - how do i turn it off?](https://superuser.com/questions/743915/screen-brightness-changes-depending-on-screen-contents-how-do-i-turn-it-off)
- [My laptop's screen dims when there's dark content. Dell, Intel, Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1019133/my-laptops-screen-dims-when-theres-dark-content-dell-intel-windows-10)

but none of the solutions given worked for me. In my Intel HD Graphics control panel there is no "Display Power Saving Technology" option, nor are there "On Battery" or "Plugged In" tabs in the power section. This problem persists on both battery and AC.

I am willing to reinstall drivers but I am not willing to reinstall Windows. I am also familiar with the command prompt and registry editor.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Here you may find your answer:[Laptop monitor brightness changes depending on image displayed](https://superuser.com/questions/540335/laptop-monitor-brightness-changes-depending-on-image-displayed/815928#815928?newreg=6116cc76c7b64f7e9d082103b0bdf4a8) Thanks to zeel

Comment: For lots of Intel based laptops try this github script to edit registry keys to disable DPST https://github.com/orev/dpst-control

Comment: In my case (Dell XPS 13 9310) it was caused by enabled HDR.

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options, then click on "Change 
plan settings" next to your active power plan.

2.Click on "Change advanced power settings."

3.Scroll down to Display, then under Enable adaptive brightness, switch it off for both the battery and plugged in modes.

Comment: This setting has been off from the start and I even tried turning it on and off again. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to disable it by right-clicking on the desktop and choosing "Intel(R) Graphics Control Panel" (it's only accessible from the desktop, not the Start Menu). "Power", "Display Power Saving Technology", "Disable". Hope that helps someone.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions an inability to access this setting in their question. I don't know whether they added that part after receiving your answer, but it doesn't look like it (no edits of the question showing for me). So the fact that your answer has gotten two upvotes within 1 1/2 months astounds me.

Comment: It's not very obvious where the Intel Graphics Control Panel lives. I never would have thought to look on the desktop's context menu if it didn't appear in the Start Menu. And this page is the first Google result for this issue. So even if it doesn't help the OP, it apparently helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the DPST control github script is worth it's own answer:

https://github.com/orev/dpst-control
(Download the zip release, run disable-dpst.bat as admin)

Intel® Display Power Saving Technology (DPST), sometimes called "adaptive brightness", is a feature of some Intel® graphics chips that automatically adjusts the screen brightness based on what is shown on the screen.

It is notably used on the Microsoft Surface line of products, as well as many others, and is the source of many complaints about display quality when systems are used in low-light settings.

DPST-Control is a command-line tool that allows one to easily disable or enable this feature. Based on the great work done [here](https://mikebattistablog.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/disable-intel-dpst-on-sp4/):

DPST-Control has been tested on Windows 10 with all recent patches (as of ~ Jan 2019). It may not work on older versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

On Desktop PC, Nvidia gtx 1060, after a full day of trying to change the windows 10 power settings and after searching for registry solution on the net to stop changes in brightness depending on the screen contents and after a full day trying to solve this anti-usability "feature" , poor PC display stability due to this stupid auto-brightness, auto-dynamic-contrast , Adaptive Brightness persisted. lost a full day with settings, registry tweaking and so on hoping to solve this issue and to disable Adaptive Brightness, Adaptive Contrast .

Solved for me: In the end, for me worked this https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/auto-brightness-dimming-in-apps/td-p/9487179?page=1 by Gregbike: unistall the poor quality software MSI X Boost App, and the display becomes stable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a fix for this. The setting is in the "Intel Graphics Command Center", which you can hopefully find by searching under the Start Menu. In the Command Center, hit the System tab on the left (the one with 4 boxes), and then click the Power tab at the top. Turn all this stuff off. Or just turn off the "Display Power Savings" option - that's the one that dims the screen when dark content is shown.

Comment: If you can't manually find this option, try this github script to edit registry keys https://github.com/orev/dpst-control

Comment: That's ridiculous amount of code to toggle a single bit, but that worked for me.  My machine had no GUI control for this, so the registry hack was my only option.  @CeePlusPlus you should re-post that as an answer so you can get some upvotes.

Comment: @remcycles sounds good, wasnt sure when I posted this if it was same issue but if it helped you then its coming up on results enough that its worth highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an *Intel Graphics Control Panel* that looks like the one on the picture below, then you need to go to *System* → *Performance* and disable the *Improved Energy Saving* option (see the red circle). At least in my case, on HP ZBook Studio G8 running Windows 10, disabling this option caused the brightness changes to stop.

(Please note that the actual English texts may differ; the language displayed is Czech.)

[image: Intel Graphics Control Panel]

Answer (score -1):

1.Change advanced power settings
2.ATI Graphics Power Settings, ATI Powerplay settings
3.Change On battery > Maximize Battery Life to Maximize Performance.

Worked for me.